# If Statement in Template

Tags: groovy, playframework

I want to create my own template and my code is:

```
#{if _arg.status.equals(models.Status.FINISHED)}
  #{doBody /}
#{/if}
```

When I pass an object reference to my tag its saying its null. If I call in my template its working as described in the docs:

```
${_arg.status}
```

The error message is:

> Template execution error
>
> Execution error occured in template
>   /app/views/tags/isNotFinished.html. Exception raised was
>   NullPointerException : Cannot get property 'status' on null object.

I am not getting any null pointer exception. What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you clarify "its saying its null" - perhaps the text of the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `_arg` is not found in the scope you're working with.  [This](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/templates#Retrievetagsparameters) seems to indicate you get `arg` implicitly in the tag.  You might try omitting the `_arg.` from the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting it really. But today I tried again with _arg and its working now as excpected. It can be closed now.